# multiple apps, sharing same data directory

Tags: android, android-manifest

my end goal is to have two apps, a "main" app (which will do all the work the user wants it to do), and a "licence" app, which will check if the app is licensed.

my question is, how can i get my licence app (com.example.myapp.licence) to share the same data directory as my main app (com.example.myapp)??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to modify manifest files for both apps, add the same 'android:sharedUserId' element to both manifest nodes.

e.g.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:sharedUserId="com.mycompany.myapp" .... />
```

If both apps have the same sharedUserId, they can access each other's data folders.

Forgot to add: obviously you need to sign both apps with the same private key with the same alias.

Comment: thanks for the response, but i have tried this method previously and i got a "permission denied" error when trying to write data, any idea as to why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766609/save-internal-file-in-my-own-internal-folder-in-android

Comment: my problem was that i had changed the sharedUserId and re-installed without uninstalling the app and clearing all data first, which caused a permission error on existing data.