# Does ENUM Singleton through several processes work in Android?

Tags: java, android

How can I write singleton to work through several processes? Is it possible?
For example I have code that works with Remote Service in Android. How can I write singleton for this purpose?

UPDATE:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;

    int a = 0;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }   
}



    void doFromFirstProcess(){
        Singleton.INSTANCE.setA(1);
    }

    void doFromSecondProcess(){
        Singleton.INSTANCE.getA(); //0
    }
```

Why does it not work? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I've answered it, but need to know more about your goal to give you alternative solution.

Comment: I  register some data in Splash Screen activity and then use this data in methods that I call from remote service.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `SharedPreferences` and maybe this will help you to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139421/multiple-apps-sharing-same-data-directory If not maybe start a new question on how to share data in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, seperate processes do not share any memory.