# Android File Read and Write

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to Android programming and so kingly pardon me if this question sounds stupid. I want to read and write from a file in an Android Program. I am aware of how to do that in Java.

Having read the documentation I wrote the following code. However I am unable to locate where this file is. According to the documentation it should be in folder data/data/package_name.

I have Samsung Galaxy S2. I launched the application, then closed it. When I went looking for the file I could not find it. I looked in My Files/data. But there is no data folder inside this data folder. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for the help.

Sources:
1. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html
2. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html#overview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private void writeFileToInternalStorage() {
      String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
      BufferedWriter writer = null;
      try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myfile.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)));
        writer.write("This is a test1." + eol);
        writer.write("This is a test2." + eol);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
        try {
          writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
      }
}   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    writeFileToInternalStorage();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: also attach logcat result when your application crashes

Comment: it doesnt crash. I am unable to locate the file where data is written to.

Comment: to access (outside of the app) the data/data/package_name folder your device must be rooted

Comment: @ManasPaldhe : see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766609/save-internal-file-in-my-own-internal-folder-in-android CommonsWare answer i hope this will solve your issue

Comment: @ManasPaldhe To Read and write in external memory so that you can view your files. Read this tutorial here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless and until your phone is rooted or you are using an emulator, I don't think you will able to see private files. Anyways, on the emulator you can always do an "adb shell" and do a "cd /data/data/package_name/" to have a look at the files.

One deprecated option is to set the flags as [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) or [MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) in the mode section of the openFileOutput(String name, int mode) function.

Else if you want to access it through your file manager, you always have the option of storing non-private data on your phone's external storage. Have a look at the [Save a File on External Storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) section to know how to do that.

Comment: I have set the MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE

Comment: Are you doing an "adb shell" and then looking at the package data directory?

Comment: I have not tried it on emulator. I am trying it on the real device.

Comment: how do I choose adb shell?

Comment: just connect your device to your machine and open a terminal on Windows/Mac/Linux and type "path/to/adb shell"

Comment: I get the error:
mpaldhe@mpaldhe-Latitude-E4300:~$ path/to/adb shell
bash: path/to/adb: No such file or directory

Comment: I meant the path to your adb script, it'll be somewhere in "android-sdk/platform-tools/adb"

Comment: FYI, I ran the code you posted on an emulator and I am able to see the contents of myfile.txt in the /data/data/package_name folder.

Comment: how do I access that folder?

Comment: Are you talking about your app folder? Look at your code, the first line will give u ur package name "package ......" e.g. de.vogella.android.socialapp in the example link u posted, do a "cd de.vogella.android.socialapp" and the do a "cd files", you'll see your mytext.txt file there.

Comment: ok! Now I am able to reach that folder through sdb, but how do I check the contents? gedit or vim doesnt work as it is not installed app in my phone. So what do I use to "see" that file?

Comment: Do a "cat myfile.txt", u will be able to see its contents.

Comment: I get error Permission denied. " cat myfile.txt
myfile.txt: Permission denied"

Comment: You'll need root access on your phone to look at the private data of apps. You can try the example on emulator or root the phone. MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE enables an app to read/write data into files of other apps and does not allow you to read/write the files from your terminal until u have root access.

Comment: it worked on emulator. I dont have root access on phone. So did not work there. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir) to get the directory on the SDCard where you can write your files. Use `null` as paramater for general files.

Path will be /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/[package]/files

Answer (score 0):

openFileOutput() func creates private file accesible by your application. Same as SharedPreferences file (private files). I means like the preference files are hidden but accessible by application in the same way your file is hidden and stored in private memory.. you can access from your code but not with file viewer..

Comment: so if I want to see the file, how to I change the preferences?

Comment: in only rooted phones these files can be reterieved from outside your app.

Comment: so where do I store the files so that the user can see in non-rooted phones?

Answer (score 0):

You can Read/ Write your File in data/data/package_name/files Folder by,

To Write

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new 
                        File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"MyFile.txt")));
bufferedWriter.write("lalit poptani");
bufferedWriter.close();
```

To Read

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new 
File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"MyFile.txt")));
String read;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

while((read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    builder.append(read);
}
Log.d("Output", builder.toString());
bufferedReader.close();
```

To Read and write in external memory so that you can view your files visually.
Read this tutorial [here.](http://java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523)

Comment: how can I see this "MyFile.txt"? I mean I want to visually see this file using text editor or something.

Comment: @Manas Paldhe as i know you can not see internal memory files. If you want to see the files then save the files in sdcard and read from sdcard.

Comment: @Manas Paldhe Read this tutorial http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523

Comment: yeah looking through it. Thanks.

Comment: @ManasPaldhe use this in AndroidManifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />..its must if you write data in external storage...