# Where is the Folder containing the Data, when I store something with getFilesDir()?

Tags: java, android, storage, internal-storage

I am writing an AndroidApp, where I save some Data by using the following File:

```
File File = new File(getFilesDir(), "Kategories.txt");
```

Then I create a `FileWriter` and so on...

First of all: IT WORKS!!! The Data gets saved and when I reopen the app, the program is able to get the data out of the Storage.

BUT, I cant find the Data-Files in the Storage!!!
I have seached it everywhere! In the Internal Storage,
in `storage/Android/data/ my package name` is not there...
Where could it be?!

PS: I use Android Studio:)

Answer (score 1):

> I cant find the Data-Files in the Storage!

The file is stored in what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You can access this using the Device File Explorer in Android Studio, but only for debuggable apps.

> In the Internal Storage, in storage/Android/data/ my package name is not there

That is what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: You have an article on every android subject :)

Answer (score 0):

If you search with an file explorer on your app you wont be able to find it, because your files are private.
Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files):

> Files saved here are accessible by only your app

If you want the files to be public have a look at this [section](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#PublicFiles).
Then you should use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` instead of `getFilesDir()`.
If you want your files to be on internal storage and public look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280085/create-a-public-folder-in-internal-storage).