# How to open a local PDF file from an Android application

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I'm trying to open a PDF file out of my Android application using Adobe Reader. When my code gets excecuted, the Adobe Reader opens but throws the following error:**'Error: The document path is not valid'** The file blabla.pdf is in my **Application** rootfolder

```
String filename = "blabla.pdf";
File file = new File(filename);
Uri internal = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(internal, "application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "U hebt geen PDF viewer geïnstalleerd op dit toestel. " +
        "Ga naar de app store en download een PDF viewer om dit bestand te openen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
startActivity(intent);
```

I want to use internal storage, not external storage.
I've used this example: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453105/android-open-pdf-file) and didn't really understand these 2 examples: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488434/internal-storage-the-document-path-is-not-valid) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766609/save-internal-file-in-my-own-internal-folder-in-android)

Comment: What do you mean by your `Application rootfolder`?

Answer (score 2):

1)First copy the file to internal storage.
 -> Keep your pdf file in assets folder.Use follwing function to copy file to internal storage

```
private void copy( InputStream in, File dst ) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( dst );
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while ( ( len = in.read( buf ) ) > 0 ) {
        out.write( buf, 0, len );
    }

    in.close( );
    out.close( );
}
```

function call for the same  :

```
File f = new File( getContext( ).getFilesDir( ), "abc.pdf" );
AssetManager assets = getContext( ).getResources( ).getAssets( );
copy( assets.open( "abc.pdf" ), f );
```

2)Now you have your file in internal storage so use following code to get file object

```
File f = new File( getContext( ).getFilesDir( )+"/"+abc.pdf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to check whether the file path is correct or not

```
if(file.exists()){
  //file path is correct 
}else{
  //file path is not correct 
}
```

Comment: This return false, I don't really know where to place the file and how to use the path

Answer (score 0):

You must set full path to file. Like in example you shown

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filename);
```

Comment: This works, but I'd like to use the internal storage method with out having to acces external storage

Comment: Application haven't access to inner data of other application. Read this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) about method. External storage is not really external.