# The document path is not valid for opening PDF in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display a PDF file from a URL but I am not able to open it with my function below. It returns me "The document path is not valid" error.

```
private void DownloadPdf(String strURL) {
        try {
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf");
            folder.mkdir();
            File file = new File(folder, "test123.pdf");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Downloader.DownloadFile(strURL, file);
            OpenPdf();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}

private void OpenPdf() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/pdf/Read.pdf");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: does this help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488434/internal-storage-the-document-path-is-not-valid

?

Comment: yes I checked that but it didnt.

Comment: you are calling openPdf() just after downloader and it works in different thread. There might be changes if the file is not yet downloaded and you are trying to open it